# views, stored procedures dialogs are displayed in right to left in AS400 i Series Navigator

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I have installed i Series Navigator Version 7.1 on Windows 10. The i series navigator itself is displayed in left to right as expected. But when creating a new View or a new Stored Procedure or a new table for example, the displayed form is in right to left. It is very problematic when I am trying to write an sql since the textbox itself is right to left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(1)  Please understand that IBM i Access for Windows is not officially supported on Windows 10. You should have installed java-based IBM i Access Client Solutions software instead.

(2)  You did not mention whether you also installed the latest service pack on top of your freshly installed IBM i Access for Windows. Perhaps your issue has been addressed in one of already released service packs. Details [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html)